# error in visual studio 2013 (compilation and running code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have visual studio 2013 installed but each time I try to compile the code or run it. When I compile it displays this:

> Error  1   error MSB4014: The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
>   System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDF10 at index 949 to specified code page.
>      at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
>      at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
>      at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
>      at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars)
>      at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.TranslateDictionary(Dictionary`2& dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketTranslatable.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.Translate[T](T& value, NodePacketValueFactory`1 factory)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeConfiguration.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.NodeContext.SendData(INodePacket packet)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)     Project1
>   Error   1   error MSB4014: The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
>   System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDF10 at index 949 to specified code page.
>      at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
>      at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
>      at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
>      at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars)
>      at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.TranslateDictionary(Dictionary`2& dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketTranslatable.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.Translate[T](T& value, NodePacketValueFactory`1 factory)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeConfiguration.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.NodeContext.SendData(INodePacket packet)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)     Project1

and when I try to run it crashes down and restart the program.

I tried downloading another version of the program (2012), but it is still the same
. 
can anyone please help?

Comment: The specific issue seems to be: `Unable to translate Unicode character \uDF10 at index 949 to specified code page`, but without code and/or other specifics, I am afraid you won't get much more help.

Comment: thank you. I will try getting my laptop formatted and will see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You fix it with Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables > System variables > Path. Click Edit and copy the content of the intentionally small text box into a text editor. Clean it up, deleting obviously wrong paths and bad characters. Some paralysis at the usual mess is expected, take no prisoners. Paste it back into the text box. Logoff + Logon to ensure the new value is in effect for all processes.