# error msb4014: the build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure. Restarting VisualStudio doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Every project I try to compile fails with the error below:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleMenu, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014: The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure.
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014: System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDF04 at index 1343 to specified code page.
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.TranslateDictionary(Dictionary`2& dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketTranslatable.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.Translate[T](T& value, NodePacketValueFactory`1 factory)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeConfiguration.Translate(INodePacketTranslator translator)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.NodeContext.SendData(INodePacket packet)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
1>C:\Users\Slench\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu\ConsoleMenu.csproj : error MSB4014:    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've looked several places, and they all mostly suggest that I restart VisualStudio. This however, does not work; the error persists.

How do I solve this problem?

I'm using VS 2013 Community Edition, running Windows 8.1

Comment: MsBuild is now [open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild), so if you want to spend some time you could probably build and debug it. From the exception, I can only tell that it tries to convert an invalid unicode character.

Comment: @JohannesEgger shouldn't MSBuild work before I'm able to compile the new MSBuild?

Comment: Hm, right, it's a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: @JohannesEgger if I were to get a fixed copy of MSBuild, where would I then put it?

Comment: @JohannesEgger Did you try to browse your source for this character?

Comment: Depends on the version of the .NET framework you installed. Mine is located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe`.

Comment: @Garath Nope, I haven't.

Comment: In order to discard possible issues: I suppose you have repaired the installation too, and that projects are compiled ok in other machines, isnt'it? Can you compile projects to another Framework version? It's a 'new' machine, or it's a 'new' error on 'old' machine?

Comment: @CapitánCavernícola it's a new error on a new machine, but I'll try to compile on a different version of the framework... That doesn't seem to do  anything either.

Comment: @JohannesEgger one more question: do you have this bug for every solution?

Comment: Try right click your project -> unload project -> right click project -> edit project -> file menu -> advanced save options -> set encoding to unicode -> save -> right click project -> reload project -> rebuild

Comment: @Garath I'm the one with the bug, and yes

Comment: @erem it was already set to unicode; following your steps did nothing

Comment: So you can't compile at all in any framework? How odd. Did you reinstall? as is a W8.1 try to "open as administrator vs" too.

Comment: @CapitánCavernícola I reinstalled VS without any luck; but I haven't yet reinstalled .net. Running as admin does nothing

Comment: I see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055886/error-in-visual-studio-2013-compilation-and-running-code and I we can supposed that formatting was the solution for that user. And seeing this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIVisualStudioUnableToTranslateUnicodeCharacterAtIndexXToSpecifiedCodePage.aspx maybe you have a Path Issue. Try to move projecto to another place (c:\test ... )

Comment: Possibly, the offending character is in your `PATH` environment variable. When checking, make sure to check both the system's `PATH` and your user's `PATH`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've seen this exception trace back a few times.  Easy to google, just query for "msbuild System.Text.EncoderFallbackException".  [This blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIVisualStudioUnableToTranslateUnicodeCharacterAtIndexXToSpecifiedCodePage.aspx) is considered the canonical answer afaik.

It is an environmental problem, caused by machines with a corrupt PATH environment variable.  Which happens entirely too often, it is a nasty global variable that gets mangled too often by a broken installer.

You fix it with Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables > System variables > Path.  Click Edit and copy the content of the intentionally small text box into a text editor.  Clean it up, deleting obviously wrong paths and bad characters.  Some paralysis at the usual mess is expected, take no prisoners.  Paste it back into the text box.  Logoff + Logon to ensure the new value is in effect for all processes.