# Error 1 The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure. Unable to translate Unicode character

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, unicode, windows-8

I have this Error since i've installed Visual Studio(Community) on my new PC.

> Error   1   The build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal
>   failure. System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate
>   Unicode character \uD928 at index 661 to specified code page. at
>   System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown,
>   Int32 index) at
>   System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*&
>   chars) at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32
>   count, EncoderNLS baseEncoder) at
>   System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars) at
>   System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value) at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.TranslateDictionary(Dictionary2&
>   dictionary, IEqualityComparer1 comparer) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketTranslatable.Translate(INodePacketTranslator
>   translator) at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodePacketTranslator.NodePacketWriteTranslator.Translate[T](T&
>   value, NodePacketValueFactory1 factory)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeConfiguration.Translate(INodePacketTranslator
>   translator)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.NodeContext.SendData(INodePacket
>   packet)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNode(Int32 nodeId,
>   INodePacketFactory factory, NodeConfiguration configuration)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider
>   nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNode(NodeConfiguration
>   configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable1
>   responses) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node,
>   BuildRequestBlocker blocker) at
>   Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission
>   submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
>   F:\Adam\ProjetVS\TestApplicationWeb1\TestApplicationWeb1\TestApplicationWeb1.csproj
>   TestApplicationWeb1

---

I sometimes **change my Windows Unicode to Japanese**. I don't remember if I changed it before or after installing VisualStudio.

Whatever, this is a quite big problem actually. I have some projects on the pot and even a simple new project does not even build. I tried to uninstall & repairs VisualStudio , but the same error remains.

**Is my Windows 8 corrupted ?**

---

Oh, also, i found an article on this error, but I don't really get what Scott means by cleaning a certain path ?

*Here's the article*

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIVisualStudioUnableToTranslateUnicodeCharacterAtIndexXToSpecifiedCodePage.aspx

What does he mean by **cleaning his path** ? **Which path** ?

---

Please help, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, Hans Passant posted : 
([error msb4014: the build stopped unexpectedly because of an internal failure. Restarting VisualStudio doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276680/error-msb4014-the-build-stopped-unexpectedly-because-of-an-internal-failure-re))

> I've seen this exception trace back a few times. Easy to google, just
>   query for "msbuild System.Text.EncoderFallbackException". This blog
>   post is considered the canonical answer afaik.
>
> It is an environmental problem, caused by machines with a corrupt PATH
>   environment variable. Which happens entirely too often, it is a nasty
>   global variable that gets mangled too often by a broken installer.
>
> You fix it with Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment
>   Variables > System variables > Path. Click Edit and copy the content
>   of the intentionally small text box into a text editor. Clean it up,
>   deleting obviously wrong paths and bad characters. Some paralysis at
>   the usual mess is expected, take no prisoners. Paste it back into the
>   text box. Logoff + Logon to ensure the new value is in effect for all
>   processes.

**Thanks Hans**, it is finally, resolved.